# Autosubmit form input with Siri

Tags: siri

I'm developing a simple web app for Iphone.
I have a form with an input text and I'd like to use the voice to search.

It works but I have to press on the return button of the keybord.
Is there a way to auto submit the query generated by Siri?

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript you can listen for the onChange event and then form.submit()